# How to remove 404 error while loading tempting?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, marionette, backbone-views

I am getting 404 error while loading  a template . I am trying to load html file using router.I make router.js file and firstpage.html .I need to display contend of **"firstpage.html"**

```
GET http://run.plnkr.co/firstpage.html 404 (Not Found)
    underscore.js:1235 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
    (index):38 ContactManager has started!
```

here is my code 
http://plnkr.co/edit/JiagaB5ztfqmxQnwgcwR?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>

       <script src="jquery.js"></script>
          <script src="json2.js"></script>   
          <script src="underscore.js"></script>
           <script src="backbone.js"></script>
             <script src="backbone.marionette.js"></script>

       <script src="common.js"></script>
        <script src="router.js"></script>
         <script src="view.js"></script>
  </head>

<body>
<div>
    <div id="header">

    </div>
    <div id="contend">


    </div>
    <div id="fotter">

    </div>
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var ContactManager = new Marionette.Application();
        ContactManager.addRegions({
            mainRegion:"#contend"
        })

        ContactManager.on("start", function(){
            console.log("ContactManager has started!");
            var routers = new R({app: ContactManager})

        });

        ContactManager.start();

    })

</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: do u try it local not in plnk?

Comment: I try on local not able to load ..do you have ID i will send my code ..Please provide your id I will send my code .please load my simple html

Answer (score 0):

In common.js you call the following

```
render.tmpl_cache[tmpl_name] = _.template(tmpl_string);
```

However the variable `tmpl_string` has an `undefined` value when passed to `_.template()`, which raises the exception. You can see this by doing

```
var tmpl_string;
_.template(tmpl_string); // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
```

This problem arises because are trying to assign a value to the `tmpl_string` inside the `$.ajax()` success callback - but this is a asynchronous function - and the `render.tmpl_cache[tmpl_name] = _.template(tmpl_string)` line will be executed while we wait for the Ajax response.

You could use [jQuery promises](http://api.jquery.com/promise/) to resolve this, so that the the variable is only passed to the `_.template()` function once you're ready.

Comment: what is solution ..could I send my code to you ? so that i am able to load html ?